# Not able to launch JMeter after a certain time

Tags: jmeter

I lately updated to the JMeter 5.0, and initially, it worked fine. But after some time, say after a day, it does not open when I try launching it. I tried launching it by clicking the jar file of JMeter, through the batch file and also by trying to run it in administrator mode, but each time it gives a different error.

When I try to open the jar file from the cmd prompt it gives following message. 
[image]

When I try to open using the batch file, I get the following error. 
[image]

If I delete the current JMeter and redownload it, it starts working fine, but after some time, it again gives the same problem.

Does anybody has any solutions??

Comment: I think some of the Jmeter files are corrupted try re-downloading Jmeter and let me know if you're having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Error 1: check JMeter log file as the error you're getting doesn't tell the full story. The file is called *jmeter.log* and normally lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation (or generated where you launch JMeter from). If it doesn't contain anything meaningful you can try [increasing JMeter log verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the certain components or the whole JMeter package by adding the next line to *jmeter.log* file

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter" level="debug" />
  ```

  This line will generate really lot information and will cause massive disk IO so JMeter will work slowly, once you figure out the problem - remove or comment this line.
- Error 2: your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable is not set up properly. [`findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) is the utility which is located under `C:\Windows\System32` and for some reason it is not in your operating system PATH. You can work it around as:

  ```
  set PATH=C:\Windows\System32;%PATH%
  ```

  once done you can start JMeter **in the same terminal window** as

  ```
  jmeter.bat
  ```

Comment: I did set the path as you told, but the error still persisted in JMeter 5.0. I downloaded the previous version of JMeter i.e. 4.0 and it is working perfectly. Must be some bug in JMeter 5.0